# JADE and ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug

I have the following expression in my nav-bar that I can't get working in JADE. It seems valid to me.

```
li(ng-class="{'active' : true}"): a(href='#') INFO SHEET
```

What am I doing wrong here? It simply doesn't apply the class as it should. If I change this to just...

```
li(class='active'): a(href='#') INFO SHEET
```

... works like a charm.

The HTML renders like so:

```
<li ng-class="{'active' : true}"><a href="#">INFO SHEET</a></li>
```

---

**EDIT:** I also tried the following:

```
li(ng-class='{active: isActive("/")}'): a(href='#') INFO SHEET
```

Where `isActive` is defined on the root controller as:

```
$scope.isActive = function(path){
  return (path === $location.path());
};
```

I set a breakpoint on the function's body in chrome, and it never breaks. There are also no errors in console. It's like Angular just isn't interpreting it for some reason.

---

Other info....

- Angular version is 1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My ng-class was at a more outer scope than my ng-controller. Moving the ng-app and root controller to the body tag fixed everything.